# How can I change certain cells in a certain column in a CSV file with C # when a certain condition is triggered?

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

So in my program the user can choose a file with an OpenFileDialog and if he wants to save the file with a SaveFileDialog, the columns and rows of the csv file should change. For this I have already tried this

**SaveFileDialog**:

```
 List<string> liste = new List<string>();
        // Build the header row into the output:
        liste.Add(String.Join(',', Enum.GetNames<CsvColumn>()));
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // neccessary only when running the code from other cultures.

        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "CVS (*.cvs)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.  
            try
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var cellArray = Regex.Split(line, @"[\t,](?=(?:[^\""]|\""[^\""]*\"")*$)")
                                            .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s.Replace("\"\"", "\""), "^\"|\"$", "")).ToArray();

                    // Check value of Betrag, only operate on it if there is a decimal value there
                    if (decimal.TryParse(cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Betrag], NumberStyles.Any, ci, out decimal betrag))
                    {
                        if (betrag >= 0)
                        {
                            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Soll] = "42590";
                            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Haben] = "441206";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Soll] = "441206";
                            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Haben] = "42590";
                        }

                        // Assuming we only write to the purple field when the green field was a decimal:
                        cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Belegnummer] = "a dummy text";
                    }

                    // Make sure you escape the columns that have a comma
                    liste.Add(string.Join(",", cellArray.Select(x => x.Contains(',') ? $"\"{x}\"" : x)) + "\n");
                }

                File.WriteAllLines(dialog.FileName, liste);
                file.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Der Gewählte Prozess wird bereits von einem anderen verwendet,\n " +
                    " bitte versuchen sie es erneut");
            }
        }
```

With that I change the header now, but now I want that when you look at the picture here:
[image: Picture1]

Operations I want to perform:

1. when the *green* field is in the **positive** area, `42590` should be in the *blue* field and `441206` in the *orange* field.
2. if the *green* value is **negative** then `441206` should be in the *blue* field and 42590 in the *orange*.
3. In the *purple* field, a dummy text should simply be automatically written.

So how do I use my C # code to fill in the fields that I have marked in the code?

**EDIT**

An Example from my Input CSV File in Text Format:

> Datum;Wertstellung;Kategorie;Name;Verwendungszweck;Konto;Bank;Betrag;Währung
> 31.10.2019;01.11.2019;;Some Text;;;;-42,89;EUR
> 31.10.2019;01.11.2019;;Some Text;;;;-236,98;EUR
> 31.10.2019;31.10.2019;;Some Text;;;;-200;EUR
> 30.10.2019;29.10.2019;;Some Text;;;;204,1;EUR
> 30.10.2019;31.10.2019;;Some Text;;;;-646,98;EUR

Comment: Just swap values in your arraycellArray .  CSV is text so you have to parse the string number to integers to test positive or negative.  Or check if first character is a negative sign.

Comment: I am not following this, if the user is displayed the cells as you show in the picture, and if the value in the green field is negative, would/could/should not this “swapping” be done in the UI? If not, it should and avoid this “swapping” of the values when writing the data to a file altogether.

Comment: @jdweng        the problem is  i dont know how to adress the colorized Column in the Code

Comment: It appears you may be opening a can worms here. Example, if you “swap” the values when the `Betrag` value is negative when writing the file. Then later, you read that file, would not the values get “swapped” back if you wrote the same data back to the file?

Comment: The split line is an array. So use : arraycellArray[3] = arraycellArray[4];

Comment: @jdweng         can you give me an code example because when I write it in an else block after the if(counter ==0) then ther stands array out of bounds

Comment: Why do you have empty rows in the CSV (see you link)?  I think error is due to the empty rows which you need to ignore.

Comment: @jdweng  when i make an breakpoint I see my cellArray have only [0] and [1] he has never more. Maybe something on my Regex.Split is broken but i dont know what is broken with that.

Comment: Do things in one complicated instruction leads to issues.  What happens when you have a blank row.  I would break the instruction into smaller pieces.  I usually use just a string split and then process the results.  Use line.Split(new char[] {'\t'}).ToArray().

Comment: @jdweng  I changed my Code with the line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }).ToArray(); but it still not working

Comment: You need to debug further. There isn't enough info to help.

Comment: Can't you somehow change the regex so that as soon as a ";" inside it is supposed to create a new index so, for example, I now have string: text1; text2; text3; text4, now it turns all texts into: cellarray [0], but I want it to be a ";" a new index power is seen in the chararray. That means: Cellarray [0] = text1 Cellarray [1] = text2 and so on

Comment: In plain english (or German) what are the conceptual names for the two account values `42590` and `441206` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task itself is pretty simple, but your attempt shows many external influences and almost no documentation. This leads to many comments to your post, but a best-practise answer really needs to address many of the smaller elements that you have so far overlooked. You already have the file management sorted out, so I'll try to focus on the array logic.

> Make sure you have run and debugged your code before posting, the output from the initial post has a few quirks:
>
> 1. Your input file uses a semi-colon, so you need to split the line by *ONLY THAT CHARACTER* in your regular expression:
>
>    ```
>    var cellArray = Regex.Split(line, @"[;](?=(?:[^\""]|\""[^\""]*\"")*$)")
>           .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s.Replace("\"\"", "\""), "^\"|\"$", "")).ToArray();
>    ```
>
>    You can't assume to split the string by multiple delimiters at the same time because only value that contain the file specific delimiter will be quote escaped.
> 2. This line is doing nothing, it looks like a previous attempt, `.Split()` and `.ToArray()` return new values, they do not manipulate the source value, as you are not using the result of this line of code just remove it:
>
>    ```
>    //line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }).ToArray();
>    ```
> 3. The header row is being written into the first cell of the first row, while it may look like it works, I challenge you to explain the intent. You have also used a semicolon as the delimiter, even though the rest of your output is using comma, so this is fixed too. You will also find it far simpler to write this header row first, before we even read the input file:
>
>    ```
>    List<String> liste = new List<string>();
>    // Build the header row into the output:
>    liste.Add("Belegdatum,Buchungsdatum,Belegnummer,Buchungstext,Verwendungszweck,Soll,Haben,Betrag,Währung");
>    ```
> 4. With the german decimal separator being a comma, you will also need to escape the `Betrag` decimal value in the output
>
>    ```
>    liste.Add(string.Join(",", cellArray.Select(x => x.Contains(',') ? $"\"{x}\"" : x)) + "\n");
>    ```
>
>    *Alternatively, you could use a semi-colon like your input data however it is still good practise to test for and escape the values that might contain the delimiter character.*
> 5. Do you really want the additional line break in the output?
>
>    It is not necessary to append each line with the `"\n"` line feed character *because* you are later using `WriteAllLines()`. This method accepts an array of lines and will inject the line break between each line for you. In file processing like this it is only necessary to manually include the line feed if you were storing the output as a single string variable and perhaps later using `WriteAllText()` to write the final output to file.
>
>    - This is often not clear when referencing different guidance material on text file manipulations, be aware of this if you copy one technique from an article that maintains an array of the lines, and a separate example that uses a single string variable or `StringBuilder` or `StringWriter` approaches.
>
>    The line from above now becomes this, note the trailing `\n` has been removed:
>
>    ```
>    liste.Add(string.Join(",", cellArray.Select(x => x.Contains(',') ? $"\"{x}\"" : x)));
>    ```

### tldr; - Show me the codez!

- **[Simple Forward Processing with Enum for Cell References](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cd10Cd)**
- **[Object Oriented Solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjxcQN)**

1. **A Simple forward processing approach**

   It makes for light-weight code but complex logic can be much harder to read, however as you parse each line into the array, you can simply manipulate the values based on your rules. We can refer to this as *sequential*, *in-line* or *forward processing* because we read the input, process and prepare the output one row at a time.

   ```
    List<string> liste = new List<string>();
    // Build the header row into the output:
    liste.Add("Belegdatum,Buchungsdatum,Belegnummer,Buchungstext,Verwendungszweck,Soll,Haben,Betrag,Währung");
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // necessary only when running the code from other cultures.

    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "CVS (*.cvs)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        try
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            int counter = 0;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                counter++;
                var cellArray = Regex.Split(line, @"[;](?=(?:[^\""]|\""[^\""]*\"")*$)")
                                        .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s.Replace("\"\"", "\""), "^\"|\"$", "")).ToArray();

                // Skip lines that fail for any reason
                try
                {
                    // Check value of Betrag, only operate on it if there is a decimal value there
                    if (decimal.TryParse(cellArray[7], NumberStyles.Any, ci, out decimal betrag))
                    {
                        if (betrag >= 0)
                        {
                            cellArray[5] = "42590";
                            cellArray[6] = "441206";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cellArray[5] = "441206";
                            cellArray[6] = "42590";
                        }

                        // Assuming we only write to the purple field when the green field was a decimal:
                        cellArray[2] = "a dummy text";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Skip lines where the Betrag is not a decimal
                        // this will cover the case when or if the first line is the header.                        
                        continue;

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // Construct a message box to help the user resolve the issue.
                    // You can use the MessageBox API to allow the user to cancel the process if you want to extend this.
                    // or remove the message altogether if you want it to silently skip the erroneous rows.
                    MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Analysieren der Eingabezeile,\n" +
                        $"{ex.Message}\n\n " +
                        $"{counter}:> {line} \n " +
                        $"{new String(' ', counter.ToString().Length)} - {cellArray.Length} Cells\n " +
                        $"|{String.Join("|", cellArray)}|\n " + 
                        "\n " +
                        " Zeile wird verworfen, weiter!");

                    continue; // advance to the next iteration of the while loop.
                }

                // Make sure you escape the columns that have a comma
                liste.Add(string.Join(",", cellArray.Select(x => x.Contains(',') ? $"\"{x}\"" : x)));
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(dialog.FileName, liste);
            file.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Der Gewählte Prozess wird bereits von einem anderen verwendet,\n " +
                " bitte versuchen sie es erneut");
        }
    }
   ```
2. **Use Named Constants**

   If you are trying to avoid an OO approach, then it can make the code easier to read by introducing some constants to refer to the indexes, there are many variations to this, but making the code more human readable will assist in future maintenance and understanding of the code.

   Define the constants, I recommend doing this inside a static class definition to group these values together, rather than just defining them a local or instance variables.

   An `enum` is another way to do this if you simply need to map strings to ints, or just want to give integer values a name.

   ```
   public enum CsvColumn
   {
       Belegdatum = 0,
       Buchungsdatum = 1,
       Belegnummer = 2,
       Buchungstext = 3,
       Verwendungszweck = 4,
       Soll = 5,
       Haben = 6,
       Betrag = 7,
       Währung = 8
   }
   ```

   Enums have the added benefit of simple commands to retrive all the names of the columns, now we can use this to build the header line *AND* as the index references in the code:

   ```
   List<string> liste = new List<string>();
   // Build the header row into the output:
   liste.Add(String.Join(',', Enum.GetNames<CsvColumn>()));
   ```

   > In previous versions of .Net the generic overload for Enum functions were not defined, in that case you will need to cast the type of the enum:
   >
   > ```
   > liste.Add(String.Join(',', Enum.GetNames(typeof(CsvColumn))));
   > ```
   >
   > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=netframework-4.7.2

   In the following logic using the enum references we need to explicitly cast the enum values to `int`. If you were using `int` constants instead, then the `(int)` explicit cast is not required. Either way now we can immediately understand the intent of the logic, wihtout having to remember what the columns at index 5 and 6 are supposed to mean.

   ```
    if (decimal.TryParse(cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Betrag], NumberStyles.Any, ci, out decimal betrag))
    {
        if (betrag >= 0)
        {
            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Soll] = "42590";
            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Haben] = "441206";
        }
        else
        {
            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Soll] = "441206";
            cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Haben] = "42590";
        }

        // Assuming we only write to the purple field when the green field was a decimal:
        cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Belegnummer] = "a dummy text";
    }
   ```

   > **View a fiddle of this implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cd10Cd**

   Of course a similar technique could be used for the `"42590"` and `"441206"` values, these must have some sort of business relevance/significance. So store them again as constant *named* string variables.

   - What you have here I refer to as *Magic Strings*, they have no meaning and could easily be corrupted during code refactoring, if the discrete value has a specific business meaning, then it should also have a specific name in the code.
3. **OO Approach**

   Using an Object-Oriented approach can mean a lot of things, in this context there are 3 different concerns or processes that we want to separate, Parsing the input, executing business logic, Formatting the output. You could simply make 3 methods that accept an array of strings, but this code becomes hard to understand, by using a structured object to model our business domain concept of a *row* from the CSV file we can remove many auumptions, for instance, which element in the array is the `Betrag` (Value).

   View the OO Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjxcQN

   > You could use this Object-Oriented concept in the above code directly, parsing each line into the object, processing and *serializing* back to a string value all in one code block, however that makes it hard to gain a higer level view of the process which is necessary to understand the code itself. Even if you do this in your head, when we look at our peer's code, we break it down into blocks or discrete steps. So to be a good coding citizen, modularise your logic into functional methods where you can, it will assist you in the future when you need to write unit tests and it will help to keep your code clean, but also to allow us to extend your code in the future.

   For this example we will create a simple model to represent each line. Note that this example takes the extra step of parsing the date fields into `DateTime` properties even though you do not need them for this example. I am deliberately using constants instead of an enum to show you a different concept. You use what ever makes sense on the day, this is still a first principals approach, there are different libraries you can use to manage serialization to and from CSV, XML, JSON and other text formats.

   If your business needs are to display this information in an application, rather than just reading a file and writing directly back out to another file, then this information may be helpful to you, otherwise it is a good habit to get into if you are just practising because larger applications or larger teams will require this level of modularisation, which itself is not specifically an OO concept... The OO part comes from where we define the processing logic, in this example the `BankRecord` contains the logic to parse the CSV string input and how to serialize back to a CSV output.

   ```
    public class BankRecord
    {
        /// <summary> Receipt Date </summary>
        public DateTime Belegdatum { get; set; }
        /// <summary> Entry Date </summary>
        public DateTime Buchungsdatum { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Sequence number</summary>
        public string Belegnummer { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Memo - Description</summary>
        public string Buchungstext { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Purpose</summary>
        public string Verwendungszweck { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Debit</summary>
        public string Soll { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Credit</summary>
        public string Haben { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Amount</summary>
        public decimal Betrag { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Currency</summary>
        public string Währung { get; set; }

        /// <summary> Column Index Definitions to simplify the CSV parsing</summary>
        public static class Columns
        {
            public const int Belegdatum = 0;
            public const int Buchungsdatum = 1;
            public const int Belegnummer = 2;
            public const int Buchungstext = 3;
            public const int Verwendungszweck = 4;
            public const int Soll = 5;
            public const int Haben = 6;
            public const int Betrag = 7;
            public const int Währung = 8;

            /// <summary>
            /// Construct a CSV Header row from these column definitions
            /// </summary>
            public static string BuildCsvHeader()
            {
                return String.Join(',',
                    nameof(Belegdatum),
                    nameof(Buchungsdatum),
                    nameof(Belegnummer),
                    nameof(Buchungstext),
                    nameof(Verwendungszweck),
                    nameof(Soll),
                    nameof(Haben),
                    nameof(Betrag),
                    nameof(Währung));
            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Parse a CSV string using the <see cref="Columns"/> definitions as the index for each of the named properties in this class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="csvLine">The CSV Line to parse</param>
        /// <param name="provider">An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information.</param>
        /// <returns>BankRecord populated from the input string</returns>
        public static BankRecord FromCSV(string csvLine, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            var cellArray = Regex.Split(csvLine, @"[\t,](?=(?:[^\""]|\""[^\""]*\"")*$)")
                    .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s.Replace("\"\"", "\""), "^\"|\"$", "")).ToArray();

            // TODO: add in some validation, today we'll just check the number of cells.
            if (cellArray.Length != 9)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Input CSV did not contain the expected number of columns. (Expected 9)");

            // The following is redimentary and doesn't perform any active error checking, the good news is that when it fails you 
            // will atleast know that it was in this specific method. Proper production level error handling is out of scope for this issue.
            var transaction = new BankRecord();
            transaction.Belegdatum = DateTime.Parse(cellArray[Columns.Belegdatum], provider);
            transaction.Buchungsdatum = DateTime.Parse(cellArray[Columns.Buchungsdatum], provider);
            transaction.Belegnummer = cellArray[Columns.Belegnummer];
            transaction.Buchungstext = cellArray[Columns.Buchungstext];
            transaction.Verwendungszweck = cellArray[Columns.Verwendungszweck];
            transaction.Soll = cellArray[Columns.Soll];
            transaction.Haben = cellArray[Columns.Haben];
            transaction.Betrag = Decimal.Parse(cellArray[Columns.Betrag], provider);
            transaction.Währung = cellArray[Columns.Währung];

            return transaction;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write this object out to a CSV string that can be interpreted using the <see cref="Columns"/> definitions as the index for each of the named properties in this class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="provider">An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information.</param>
        /// <returns>CSV string that represents this record./returns>
        public string ToCSV(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return String.Join(',',
                CsvEscape(Belegdatum, provider),
                CsvEscape(Buchungsdatum, provider),
                CsvEscape(Belegnummer, provider),
                CsvEscape(Buchungstext, provider),
                CsvEscape(Verwendungszweck, provider),
                CsvEscape(Soll, provider),
                CsvEscape(Haben, provider),
                CsvEscape(Betrag, provider),
                CsvEscape(Währung, provider));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple routine to format a value for CSV output
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to serialize</param>
        /// <param name="provider">An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information.</param>
        /// <returns>Value escaped and safe for direct inclusion in a CSV output</returns>
        private string CsvEscape(object value, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return string.Empty;
            string stringValue = String.Format(provider, "{0}", value);
            if (stringValue.Contains(','))
                return $"\"{stringValue}\"";
            else
                return stringValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Format a Date value for CSV output
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to serialize</param>
        /// <param name="provider">An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information.</param>
        /// <remarks>Simple override to allow for common syntax between types, removes the need to the caller to understand the differences</remarks>
        /// <returns>Value escaped and safe for direct inclusion in a CSV output</returns>
        private string CsvEscape(DateTime value, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            string stringValue = String.Format(provider, "{0:d}", value);
            if (stringValue.Contains(','))
                return $"\"{stringValue}\"";
            else
                return stringValue;
        }
    }
   ```

   The following is the process logic:

   ```
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // neccessary only when running the code from other cultures.

    // I'll leave this in, but don't call your list, "liste" instead give it some context or meaing, like "records" or "transactions"
    List<BankRecord> liste = new List<BankRecord>();

    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "CVS (*.cvs)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string line;

        // Read the file line by line.  
        try
        {
            #region Parse the input File
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    liste.Add(BankRecord.FromCSV(line, ci));
                }
                catch
                {
                    // TODO: re-raise or otherwise handle this error if you want.
                    //       today we will simply ignore erroneous entries and will suppress this error
                }
            }
            #endregion Parse the input File


            #region Evaluate your business rules
            // Evaluate your business rules here, natively in C#, no arrays or indexes, just manipulate the business domain object.
            // assuming that Belegnummer is a sequencing number, not sure if it is from the start of this file or a different context...
            // This just demonstrates a potential reason for NOT encapsulating the processing logic inside the BankRecord class.
            int previousLineNumber = 47; // aribrary start...
            foreach (var transaction in liste)
            {
                // Check value of Betrag, only operate on it if there is a decimal value there
                if (transaction.Betrag >= 0)
                {
                    transaction.Soll = "42590";
                    transaction.Haben = "441206";
                }
                else
                {
                    transaction.Soll = "441206";
                    transaction.Haben = "42590";
                }

                transaction.Belegnummer = $"#{++previousLineNumber}";
            }
            #endregion Evaluate your business rules


            #region Now write to the output
            List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();
            outputLines.Add(BankRecord.Columns.BuildCsvHeader());
            outputLines.AddRange(liste.Select(x => x.ToCSV(ci)));

            File.WriteAllLines(dialog.FileName, outputLines);
            file.Close();
            #endregion Now write to the output

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Der Gewählte Prozess wird bereits von einem anderen verwendet,\n " +
                " bitte versuchen sie es erneut");
        }
    }
   ```

   Final Output:

   ```
   Belegdatum,Buchungsdatum,Belegnummer,Buchungstext,Verwendungszweck,Soll,Haben,Betrag,Währung
   31.10.2019,01.11.2019,#48,Some Text,,42590,441206,"50,43",EUR
   31.10.2019,01.11.2019,#49,Some Text,,441206,42590,"-239,98",EUR
   31.10.2019,31.10.2019,#50,Some Text,,441206,42590,-500,EUR
   ```

   | Belegdatum | Buchungsdatum | Belegnummer | Buchungstext | Verwendungszweck | Soll | Haben | Betrag | Währung |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 31.10.2019 | 01.11.2019 | #48 | Some Text |  | 42590 | 441206 | 50,43 | EUR |
   | 31.10.2019 | 01.11.2019 | #49 | Some Text |  | 441206 | 42590 | -239,98 | EUR |
   | 31.10.2019 | 31.10.2019 | #50 | Some Text |  | 441206 | 42590 | -500 | EUR |

Comment: at first thanks for your detailed answer. I editet my Code from my Question with your Code so you can see at which point im standing. When I write it like that at this point: liste.Add(String.Join(',', Enum.GetNames<CsvColumn>())); "Enum.GetNames (Type)" method is not generic and therefore cannot be used with type arguments "  When I remove this Line and try to start it then he jumps every time in the catch statment because the cellArray is out of bounds.

Comment: Sorry about that, you didn't specify which version or framework, so I went with the "current". I have updated my response, please in the future try not to update the original code sample as your original request will bet out of sync from the comments and solutions offered.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tipp, but how can I solve that problem?

Comment: I've added in a link to the C# docs, you the non-generic version: `liste.Add(String.Join(',', Enum.GetNames(typeof(CsvColumn))));` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Ok now I changed it but when the code wants to jump into this if blocl:  if (decimal.TryParse(cellArray[(int)CsvColumn.Betrag], NumberStyles.Any, ci, out decimal betrag))  is there standing: "The index was outside the array range"

Comment: What you haven't shown is an example of the input file, in raw form, I suspect either there are blank lines or it doesn't have the number of cells in the all the lines that this code requires. You need to add some validation logic in a production system, for now when it fails, what is the length of the array? I can update the post with some simple validation that will skip erroneous rows, but any other tips we should probably take offline.

Comment: It would be nice the update with that simple validation that skips erroneous rows

Comment: Updated, see how we use an inner try-catch block. Your outer block is still valid, the inner one handles only the processing logic, the outer one handles the file read/writes. This is another good argument for moving towards the OO solution, by separating the IO and the logic, you can isolate specific errors and handle them in a context where you have a lot more information about the error. Steep learning curve, but it makes sense once you do it a few times.

Comment: Now they only save the Header Text into the new Cs File, I editet the Question so you can see how the input File look like

Comment: You'll need to show the raw text of the file, looking at the file through an editor or spreadsheet hides the underlying implementation. Hopefully the information in the message box for each line that fails is helpful, certainly posting that here would help but now we're getting into general debugging techniques and it is out of scope for this specific question

Comment: The Information with the Line that fails are very Helpful and I changed the Edit with the Raw Text

Comment: Please read through my answer again, with the raw input I have subtly changed things. Also have a look at this working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrc4A0 1. Need to put `;` in your regex, 2. Need to skip the first line if your input has headers.

Comment: Ok, having built a better OO example, it is now clear that you **MUST** define the specific delimiter to use for the input file, we can't easily assume to support all delimiters at the same time because different delimiters are used to by-pass escaping. https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjxcQN change your input delimiter to just `';'`

Comment: So this is my full C# (WPF) Code behind: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZjRTs0   but for the new CSV File he just place the header Text and nothing more

Comment: Have a look at my comments in FromCSV method in https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6p6Le your regex needs to split on semi-colon, not tab or comma. This turns out to have been your main issue all along ;) I tried calling it out a few comments ago

Comment: now it works, thank you very much for your extensive and detailed help. I'm going to experiment with your code to get a better understanding of it. Thank you :)

Comment: Have fun, but take the file complexity out of it, so prototype with the code shown in the fiddles, having too many variables (as in code changes or unknown or untested routines) at once makes it hard to isolate the specific cause of issues.